# OAuthException (#1500) The url you supplied is invalid

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to develop an app which allows to post links on user timeline. I'm using:

```
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', {
  message     : that.container.find('#social-message').val(),
  name        : 'App name',
  link        : 'http://www.blog.domain.pl'
}, function (response) {
  console.info('Facebook submit response:', response);
});
```

It's throwing me an error. But, when I'm changing the url provided in link property to: `http://www.domain.pl` it works correctly. How can I post any link from subdomain?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: It's in the title of the question

Comment: That's just an example URL (non-existing one): `http://blog.domain.pl` - it doesn't work. But, `http://www.domain.pl` - works.

Comment: How can you share a non-existing url? It doesn't depends whether or not the url is a sub-domain. But you should share a valid url.

Comment: In the app I'm sharing an existing URL (no worries), but it doesn't matter in this case.